# Bind to list item record from template dropdownlist of choice fields?

Tags: web-part

I have created  template field with a ddl.  I have instantiated an SPGridview and the ddl shows up but only with the default choice values.  How do I bind to the actual values of the List item record?

Here is my code:

```
    public class ItemTemplateDDL:ITemplate
{
    private string _NAME;
    private string _DATAVALUEFIELD;
    private string _DATATEXTFIELD;
    private SPWeb _SITE;
    private string _LISTNAME;

    public ItemTemplateDDL(string ddlName, string DataValueField, string DataTextField, SPWeb site, string list)
    {
        this._DATATEXTFIELD = DataTextField;
        this._DATAVALUEFIELD = DataTextField;
        this._LISTNAME = list;
        this._SITE = site;
        this._NAME = DataTextField;

    }


    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
        ddl.DataBinding += new EventHandler(ddl_Databinding);
        ddl.SelectedIndexChanged +=new EventHandler(ddl_SelectedIndexChanged);

        container.Controls.Add(ddl);
    }

    private void ddl_Databinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
          SPList dataList = _SITE.Lists[_LISTNAME];


          SPFieldChoice field = (SPFieldChoice)dataList.Fields[_DATAVALUEFIELD];


          ddl.DataSource = field.Choices;

    }

    private void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string h = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question:

```
private void ddl_Databinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
          SPList dataList = _SITE.Lists[_LISTNAME];


          SPFieldChoice field = (SPFieldChoice)dataList.Fields[_DATAVALUEFIELD];
          ddl.DataSource = field.Choices;

          SPGridViewRow container = (SPGridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;
          ddl.Text = DataBinder.Eval(container.DataItem, _NAME).ToString(); 




    }
```